# 1990s Aliens crash land in woods and enters family house

Tags: story-identification

I saw this show in the 90's of aliens crashing near the woods. The family is recording them with a camera. They eventually make it into the house. I believe it was on KCOP-TV. It was most likely a TV movie. Any help would be great! Thanks

Comment: Show or movie? You don't remember anything else? You're sure you saw it in the 90s? When?

Comment: I want to say sometime between 90-94 .. It was some type of tv movie. The aliens landed near the woods, so they all ran to see what happen. They can see them coming off the ship and ran back to the house. Eventually, they make it inside the house. One of them has the camera and it's all dark and finds the alien in a room once he turns on the light on the camera. I wish I had more info.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in "found footage" style, it might be this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFO_Abduction_(film)

And the film itself:

I haven't watched it, but the contents sound similar, so it's worth to take a look.

Comment: the aliens break in through windows on the second floor. I can't remember much, but soon the members of the family disappear one by one, till there's only the son left. he hides in the bathroom with the camcorder videotaping his last goodbye or something. then he goes out alone in the hallway into a dark room. he turns around and there's an alien that was hiding behind the door coming at him. the alien takes the camera or something, cuz that's how it ends.